# Apache: Can't open .php files

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I want to start learning PHP, so I installed Apache2, MySQL and PHP5 on my Ubuntu 10.10 today. For some reason, when I try to open a file other than index.html from the default directory /var/www/, I either get a 404 error or I get a prompt to download the php file. I googl'd all over and I can't find a solution.

When I do http://localhost/index.html, it works, and displays whatever I write in index.html. When I change /index.html to /test.php, I get an error saying "The requested URL /test.php was not found on this server".

When I try /var/www/index.html or file:///var/www/index.html, again, index.html appears although it appears differently. When opened with http://localhost/index.html I only get "It works!", but with /var/www/index.html I get "It works! 
This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet."

And then when I change /var/www/index.html to /test.php, I get a prompt to download test.php.

In my .conf files, the default directory is set to /var/www/, so this is very weird.

Edit:

Did some checking, and it seems that when I run http://localhost it's set to a directory in the httpd directory. I tried putting my test.php file there, and still I'm getting 404. But when I write the full path, again, I get a download prompt.

This problem is really confusing... thanks to all helpers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. seems that I found the solution myself. For some weird reason, I have like 4 different localhost default folders. I had to search manually through each folder containing index.html and move test.php there. Eventually, I found an obscure folder somewhere in the /usr/ folder, moved test.php to there, and it worked. Apparently I have like 4 different versions for each .conf file, and each one states a different thing. Only one of them works.

Phew. What a relief.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if PHP has been enabled in the Apache `httpd.conf` file. See here for further details: http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Apache/Using-Apache-and-PHP-on-Mac-OS-X/

Comment: I know you're on Ubuntu and not OSX, but the configuration for Apache should be the same.

Comment: It's definitely enabled, I added the LoadModule and AddType myself after installing Apache.

Comment: Did you restart apache afterwards?